# How to configure RSpec to load monkey patched classes

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I have extended the string class as follows:

```
class String
  def last_character
    self[-1]
  end
end
```

I have places the string.rb file in the lib as follows:

```
lib/core_extensions/string.rb
```

I have tested the setup and I can use the last_character method in a Rails console.

However, when I run an RSpec test for a class that uses the extended String class it gives me an error:

```
undefined method `last_character' for " ":String
```

Do I have to tell RSpec to load these class extension files somehow?

Comment: How does your Rails app load this custom extension? Have you created an initializer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to eagerly/explicitly load your custom extensions in the `rails_helper.rb`

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('lib/core_extensions/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
```

#### Alternative approach

Add that folder to `eager_load_paths` and set `config.eager_load = true` in `config/environments/test.rb`.

Comment: Thank you for that Sergio. Would you know why I have to explicitly do this with Rspec? In other words why doesn't RSpec just load them automatically?

Comment: @chell: I'm guessing because you either a) don't load rails environment in rspec or b) don't have that folder in autoload_paths/eager_load_paths.

Comment: Hi Sergio, I think I do load rails environment in rspec as I have the following in my rails_helper file: require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__).  I think your point b) may be the issue: I have this in my application.rb:  config.eager_load_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib   However, inside of environment/tests.rb   I have: config.eager_load = false

Comment: I just tested changing config.eager_load to true and removing the code you gave me and it all works. So really the answer should be that I needed to set config.eager_load=true to load my custom extensions.

Comment: @chell: eager loading in test is an alternative approach. The one in my answer is also very popular.

Answer (score 1):

Does your spec have `require "rails_helper"`?

Have you tried restarting Spring?

Comment: Yes I have require 'rails_helper' and I have restarted Spring.

Comment: If you're able to share your repo on GitHub I can take a look.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to share my repository.